# Testing angularjs with dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm pretty new to testing in AngularJS and I'm getting confused as hell. I have a controller that is dependent on a service that is dependent on a value. I've written very basic tests for the controller just to get to grips with it and they all pass when I don't have the value injected into the service. However, when I inject the value into the service I get `Unknown provider`  error on all the tests for the controller.

My code is below:

## Controller

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .controller('testController', function($scope, testService) {

        $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
            $scope.setup();
        });

        $scope.testFunction = function() {
            $scope.result = 1;
        };

        $scope.setup = function() {
            testService.superAwesomeFunction();
            $scope.enterValue = 1;
        };

    });
```

## Service

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .service('testService', ['URLRoute', function(URLRoute) {

        var superAwesomeFunction = function() {
            var URLRequest = URLRoute;
            console.log(URLRequest);
        };

        return {
            superAwesomeFunction: superAwesomeFunction
        };
    }]);
```

## Value

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .value('URLRoute', {
        url: 'https://abcdefghijklmnop.com/api',
    });
```

## test.controller.test.js

```
'use strict';
describe('testController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $controller, 
        $rootScope, 
        $scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $controller('testController', { 
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));

    describe('$scope.$on(ionicView.enter)', function() {
        it ('$scope.$on calls $ionicView.enter', function() {
            spyOn($scope, '$on').and.callThrough();
            $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter');
            expect($scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$ionicView.enter');
        });
    });

    describe('$scope.testFunction', function() {
        it('Sets the value of result to 1', function() {
            $scope.testFunction();
            expect($scope.result).toEqual(1);
        });
    });

    describe('$scope.setup', function() {
        it('Sets up stuff for the view after it has loaded', function() {
            $scope.setup();
            expect($scope.enterValue).toEqual(1);
        });
    });


});
```

When the tests run now, the error I get is:

`Unknown provider: URLRouteProvider <- URLRoute <- testService`

Any help appreciated, been very confused with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
.service('testService', [ function(URLRoute) {

    var superAwesomeFunction = function() {
        var URLRequest = URLRoute;
        console.log(URLRequest);
    };

    return {
        superAwesomeFunction: superAwesomeFunction
    };
}]);
```

Got it from : [lostechies](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/)

Comment: Yeah so this isn't valid Angular, but what I think you meant was to strip out the square brackets for minifying it and trying it that way? If so it results in the same error